# Ошибка ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris


iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier()

dt = dt.fit(X_train, y_train)

predicted = dt.predict(X_test, y_test)
```

В чем проблема? Модель обучается на таких же данных, но ничего не предсказывает. Вылазит ошибка

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.Use a.any() or a.all()

Сохранял данные в DataFrame, но все так же ошибка.

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `dt.predict(X, check_input=True)` ожидает два аргумента - матрицу значений, на основании которой будут делаться предсказания и булевый флаг `check_input`. Вы передали в качестве второго параметра массив правильных значений вместо скалярного значения. В коде `dt.predict` есть проверка `if check_input:` - на этой строке кода выпадет исключительная ситуация, т.к. конструкция `if np.array([1, 0, 0, 2])` - не может быть однозначно проверена.

Нет смысла передавать в `dt.predict()` заранее известный ответ - `y_test`.

Правильно делать так:

```
predicted = dt.predict(X_test)
```

---

Если вы хотите проверить точность предсказаний то можно воспользоваться методом `.score()`:

```
In [5]: dt.score(X_test, y_test)
Out[5]: 0.9473684210526315
```